# how create table with text inside in Freemarker Template?

Tags: java, freemarker

I have to create a table in FTL with 2 rows and 5 columns that should have some text inside in each cell of table.
How to achieve in FTL.

Comment: FTL has no "tables". If your Freemarker template generates HTML, then you need to generate the appropriate HTML tags `<table>` etc

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I mean the output is to be generated in PDF.I have blank page right now as i have commented other developer's code which is generating some text in that PDF from FTL file.

Comment: Freemarker can not directly "generate PDF". It probably generates some markup to be used with another tool then generates the PDF. Maybe Apache FOP

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of FTL with a table that I have used in my app:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1">
    <tr class="tableHeader">
        <td>Rep Number</td>
        <td>Order Number</td>
        <td>IO Guid</td>
        <td>Last Update Date</td>
        <td>Last Updated By</td>
    </tr>
    <#foreach order in orders>                  
        <tr class="tableBody">
            <td>${order.salesrepNumber}</td>
            <td>${order.orderNumber}</td>
            <td>${order.ioGuid}</td>
            <td>${order.lastUpdateDate?datetime}</td>
            <td>${order.lastUpdatedByUser}</td>
        </tr>
    </#foreach>                             
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the ex.How can I merge example like above in below code where some variables are used to populate some text.                        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="letter">
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block font-family="Arial" font-size="11pt">
            <fo:block font-size="26pt" font-weight="bold" color="rgb(31, 73, 125)" space-after="0.4in">
                ~:BACKGROUND:~
            </fo:block>
            <fo:block>
                ~:BACKGROUND_PAGE_TEXT_FIRST_PARAGRAPH_PART_1:~</fo:block>
 </fo:block>
</fo:flow>
</fo:page-sequence>

Comment: The example I gave has a variable **orders** that was passed in the model to the page. It is in the foreach block, and we refer to **order** in each table cell. You just need to refer to any object you pass with the ${VAR_NAME} convention. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @B-Wieg , will try soon and reply if this helps